# Modular arithmatic, basic question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How does this:

$2x + 3 \equiv -1 \pmod {10}$

directly lead to this:

$2x = 6 \pmod{10}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2x+3\equiv -1\mod10\iff 2x\equiv -4\mod10\\\iff2x\equiv -4+10\mod10\iff2x\equiv 6\mod10$$

Comment: so to be accurate, if i must express in mod 10, the number on the right must be between 1 and 9, correct?

Comment: @user3308043: Not at all. It could be $0,$ more than $10,$ or negative. Basically, whatever is most useful. For example, while $$3x=2\pmod{10}$$ is not particularly revealing, we can deduce a great deal by changing to the equivalent $$3x=12\pmod{10}$$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $10=0\pmod{10}.$ Thus, $a+10=a\pmod{10}$ for any $a$.

Comment: 2x + 3 = -1 (mod 10) --> 2x + 3 = 9 (mod 10) --> 2x = 9 - 3 (mod 10)??

Comment: Precisely right! It's worth noting that those are equivalences all the way, not just one-directional implications.